# How to set default Calendar when your Android has multiple calendars?

Tags: android, calendar

Consider a scenario where an Android device is configured with a Google account. Now if a calendar event is created, the user can select either default(Phone calendar) or Google one. How to set the Google calendar as default the one?

Comment: That's up to the user, you can't make their decision for them.

Comment: Belongs on android.stackexchange.com

Comment: I would appreciate if anyone can give some pointers.

Comment: Star the issue here to vote for it to be fixed: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3920

Answer (score 0):

My solution (tested on my LG P500, Android 2.3.3) :

1. Install Jorte calendar, it's free
2. At Jorte's interface open "preferences" -> "Choose calendars",  select only "right" calendar.
3. Close Jorte and go to default android calenar. Now your "right" calendar is default.

Comment: Having to resort to using an alternative 3rd party app that is overly complicated should not be a qualifying answer.